Handling malformed PDF with MuPDF
I am using MuPDF to read some PDF documents, and recently I have started getting some malformed PDFs coming from Google GSuite where the hex header in the beginning has some additional bytes added in front.
According to specs I read online (https://www.usna.edu/CyberDept/sy110/resources/01.general/fileheaders.html), PDF documents are supposed to begin with hex "25 50 44 46" which is "%PDF" in ASCII. For some reason the GSuite PDFs have more bytes in the beginning infront of it:
0ade b503 2550 4446 2d31 2e35 0a25 bff7  ....%PDF-1.5.%..
I have no idea why this was done. It's causing even the linux "file" command to mis-identify the file as only "data". Somehow Chrome and other PDF readers can still open up the file, but MuPDF cannot do it - it thinks the PDF has zero pages.
One workaround is to strip out the leading bytes before the proper PDF header bytes if they are found, but is there a more elegant solution to this problem, like a special parameter that can be passed to MuPDF?

Can you send one of this pdf file?

Hi, unfortunately I cannot provide a sample as it does contain alot of confidential information. But thanks for letting me know MuPDF doesn't have an option to deal with it. I am using a workaround for now.

It's completely legal. Per the ISO 32000-2 spec:
"The PDF file begins with the 5 characters “%PDF–” and byte offsets shall be calculated from the PERCENT SIGN (25h).
NOTE 1 This provision allows for arbitrary bytes preceding the %PDF- without impacting the viability of the PDF file and its byte offsets."
(Earlier versions of the spec limited this to 1024 bytes, maybe? From memory).
I'm sure MuPDF knows how to read such files, because they aren't uncommon, so I would suspect something else is going on here. I'd report it to them directly and see what they say.

*It's completely legal. Per the ISO 32000-2 spec:
"The PDF file begins with the 5 characters “%PDF–”* - well, this does show that a PDF file starts with “%PDF–”. Period. NOTE 1 This provision allows for arbitrary bytes preceding the %PDF- without impacting the viability of the PDF file and its byte offsets." - ok, so a PDF file may be embedded in some other file, and even then any mentioning of an offset from the start of the file in the PDF spec here is is ensured to mean from the start of the “%PDF–” and not from the start of the file the PDF is embedded in.

If the interpretation in my previous comment does not convince you, simply remember that notes are not normative.

"(Earlier versions of the spec limited this to 1024 bytes, maybe? From memory)." - No. The previous spec (ISO 32000-1) and the earlier PDF references all said that the PDF file starts with “%PDF–”. But those earlier PDF references included an annex about Adobe Acrobat implementation notes, and there it was mentioned that Acrobat accepts files with the “%PDF–” anywhere in the initial 1024 bytes of the file. But this merely was an implementation note, nothing normative, and the PDF references were considered not normative in nature anyways.

The question is in effect can MuPDF correct a corrupt PDF ?
The answer should be yes for viewing but no for saving, however some versions may have other abilities!

If MuPDF detects a save is warranted (usually problems with annotation), it may like Acrobat Reader, offer to save a fixed file.

Here I have injected the first line as per your minimal example and reference text.
MuPDF viewer will like Acrobat Reader, gloss over the rendering issue, but may fail on any other incorrect contents (I added some others). Then should raise an error message. however unlike Acrobat reader which saves its edits. MuPDF Viewer is not designed to save fixed faulty files. For that we have Mutool.

Depending on other introduced errors (I added a few) it may need a full cleaning, thus if this does not work you may need to dig deeper.
It fixes the head and the tail and much in between.
mutool clean -cgggst "Input.pdf" "Output-fixed.pdf"

Collateral damage is reduced, however the "Header" will likely be raised from 1.5 (PDF version 6) to Version 8 (1.7)!

Answer
For to how to fix a PDF file with 4 extra bytes is the file should simply work with or without them. But to remove them should be simply start the filestream counting from 0 start from byte 4. There are many small single command line binary tools for Windows. Perhaps the best PDF relevant is "Middle.exe" from Didier Stevens. https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/binary-tools/
(current download=https://www.didierstevens.com/files/software/BinaryTools.zip)
A limitation is "file part must fit in memory"
middle.exe "bad.pdf" 0x4 "fixed.pdf"

